# Spark splitting a column into array and aggregate calculation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame in the following format:

```
COL_1    COL_2    COL_3
-----    -----    -----
TEXT1     TEXT2    ["www.a.com/abc", "www.b.com/dgh", "www.c.com/axy", "www.a.com/xyz"]
TEXT3     TEXT4    ["www.a.com/abc", "www.d.com/dgh", "www.a.com/axy", "www.f.com/xyz", "www.f.com/xyz", "www.a.com/xyz"]
TEXT5     TEXT6    ["www.v.com/abc", "www.c.com/axy"]
```

All the columns are strings. What I want to do in spark:

- Split COL_3 to separate URLs.
- Extract the domain name, then calculate the percentage of the URLs that are from domain "a.com" in that row.
- If the percentage of "a.com" exceeds certain amount **in that row** (50% of the URLs in that row are from a.com for example), I want to map each URL path to a separate row with COL_1 and COL_2.

For the example above, the output would be similar to the following:

```
COL_1    COL_2    COL_MAP_REDUCED
-----    -----    -----
TEXT1     TEXT2    abc
TEXT1     TEXT2    xyz
TEXT3     TEXT4    xyz
TEXT3     TEXT4    axy
```

I am not looking for someone to solve the problem for me, I am looking for guidance on how to start as my google-foo is failing me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val df = // your dataframe creation code
    val res = df.map{r=>
    val col3 = r.getAs[String](“col_3”)
    val col2= r.getAs[String](“col_2”)
    val col1= r.getAs[String](“col_1”)
    //operate on col3 as you wish
    val col4_ = yourFunc(col3)

    //if col4 is of type Seq or Array then you can flatten it by using flatMap or explode function

    val col4 = Seq("x","y")    
    var explodedResult = Seq[Tuple4[String,String,String,String]]()

    col4.foreach{ element =>
    explodedResult = explodedResult :+ (col1, col2, col3, element)
    explodedResult    
    }.flatMap(identity(_))
```

New dataframe ‘res’ will have all existing columns plus the new evaluation result.

If store this dataframe then a lot of data will be duplicated. You can rather store the result as an array too like `(col1:String,col2:String,col3:String,col4:Seq[String])`. If you need to repeat each value in col4 in a separate row then you can `explode` function which will explode each row of col4 into a row of whole dataframe. The syntax for that is `df.withColumn("col4", explode(col("col4")).show()`

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer. What about having a separate row for each col4 output (COL_MAP_REDUCED in my example)?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If this works then pleases upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|COL_1|COL_2|COL_3                                                                                                 |
+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|TEXT1|TEXT2|["www.a.com/abc", "www.b.com/dgh", "www.c.com/axy", "www.a.com/xyz"]                                  |
|TEXT3|TEXT4|["www.a.com/abc", "www.d.com/dgh", "www.a.com/axy", "www.f.com/xyz", "www.f.com/xyz", "www.a.com/xyz"]|
|TEXT5|TEXT6|["www.v.com/abc", "www.c.com/axy"]                                                                    |
+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> Split COL_3 to separate URLs.

```
scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("COL_3", regexp_replace(col("COL_3"), "[\\] \" \\[]",""))
                   .withColumn("COL_3", explode(split(col("COL_3"), ","))) 

scala> df1.show(false)
+-----+-----+-------------+
|COL_1|COL_2|COL_3        |
+-----+-----+-------------+
|TEXT1|TEXT2|www.a.com/abc|
|TEXT1|TEXT2|www.b.com/dgh|
|TEXT1|TEXT2|www.c.com/axy|
|TEXT1|TEXT2|www.a.com/xyz|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.a.com/abc|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.d.com/dgh|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.a.com/axy|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.f.com/xyz|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.f.com/xyz|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.a.com/xyz|
|TEXT5|TEXT6|www.v.com/abc|
|TEXT5|TEXT6|www.c.com/axy|
+-----+-----+-------------+
```

> Extract the domain name, then calculate the percentage of the URLs
>   that are from domain "a.com" in that row.

```
scala> val df2 = df1.filter(col("COL_3").like("%a.com%"))

scala> df2.show
+-----+-----+-------------+
|COL_1|COL_2|        COL_3|
+-----+-----+-------------+
|TEXT1|TEXT2|www.a.com/abc|
|TEXT1|TEXT2|www.a.com/xyz|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.a.com/abc|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.a.com/axy|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|www.a.com/xyz|
+-----+-----+-------------+
```

> If the percentage of "a.com" exceeds certain amount in that row (50%
>   of the URLs in that row are from a.com for example), I want to map
>   each URL path to a separate row with COL_1 and COL_2.

You can get percentage by getting group count for `col_1` and `col_2` from dataframe `df1` and calculate with same count with datafram `df2`.

**For your desire output**

```
scala> df2.withColumn("COL_MAP_REDUCED", split(col("COL_3"),"/")(1)).drop("COL_3").show
+-----+-----+---------------+
|COL_1|COL_2|COL_MAP_REDUCED|
+-----+-----+---------------+
|TEXT1|TEXT2|            abc|
|TEXT1|TEXT2|            xyz|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|            abc|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|            axy|
|TEXT3|TEXT4|            xyz|
+-----+-----+---------------+
```